# Find type of bluetooth device whether mobile or laptop's or mac pc's

Tags: android, bluetooth, device

I am developing an android game application played using bluetooth. While searching for bluetooth device, results contain both mobile devices as well as mac pc/laptops. I would like to list only the mobile devices in my result list. Is it possible to find whether the device detected is mobile device or not?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you have [BluetoothDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html) you can call [getBluetoothClass](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getBluetoothClass%28%29). Smart phones are expected to have [PHONE_SMART](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html#PHONE_SMART) value, while computers should have COMPUTER_* values (for example [COMPUTER_DESKTOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html#COMPUTER_DESKTOP) or [COMPUTER_LAPTOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html#COMPUTER_LAPTOP)).

Comment: can i get the device spec like bluetooth_headet or bluetooth connectivity in car from this method

Comment: do anyone know what is code for gamepad or joystick