# How to differentiate the connected bluetooth device in android programmatically?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-broadcast

***Whether it is a bluetooth headset or mobile phones?***

how to differentiate the bluetooth headset and bluetooth enabled android device in android code.

I am developing a small application,in that I have a feature of blocking the data transfer via bluetooth but it need to allow communication via bluetooth headset.

- I referred the examples and codes in that they suggest me to
  pair/unpair the bluetooth devices only.
  [Android: How to pair bluetooth devices programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834318/android-how-to-pair-bluetooth-devices-programmatically)

  ```
                           or else
  ```
- get all connected devices.
  [In Android, how to get the profile of a connected bluetooth device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556797/in-android-how-to-get-the-profile-of-a-connected-bluetooth-device)
- Whether can i get any broadcast message in device related to type of
  device connection?

Please help me on this to differentiate the connected bluetooth device as headset /android devices(mobile phone).etc.,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should have a look at this question. this has all the answer you need -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989847/find-type-of-bluetooth-device-whether-mobile-or-laptops-or-mac-pcs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Once you scan and find a `BluetoothDevice` call the method `BluetoothDevice.getBluetoothClass()`. This will return a `BluetoothClass` object and the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.html) states the following:

> Represents a Bluetooth class, which describes general characteristics
>   and capabilities of a device. For example, a Bluetooth class will
>   specify the general device type such as a phone, a computer, or
>   headset, and whether it's capable of services such as audio or
>   telephony.

So before you allow the user to select the device to connect to, or to filter the list of `BluetoothDevice`s shown, try seeing if the `BluetoothClass` has the correct device type.

```
BluetoothClass bluetoothClass = bluetoothDevice.getBluetoothClass();
if(bluetoothClass.getDeviceClass() == BluetoothClass.Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_HEADPHONES) {
    // allow user to select this device. I'm not sure exactly which type
    // headphones will be but this is a good guess. You can connect to
    // your Bluetooth headset to find out for sure.
}
```

The different device class constants can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html) in case you want to differentiate by device class further.