# How to identify the device type of bluetooth paired device

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have a list of paired devices connected over bluetooth. But i want to categorize them as iPhone or Android. How is this possible?

Comment: in general, you can't know which OS type is on that device.. You can only check by services available, and *probably* differentiate them somehow this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot check OS version of the device.

Please refer to the below link. [How to differentiate the connected bluetooth device in android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328653/how-to-differentiate-the-connected-bluetooth-device-in-android-programmatically)