# Get android bluetooth device type

Tags: android, bluetooth

How to check if available Bluetooth device is a mobile or laptop or any other device ? I have searched through BluetoothDevice API but and found getType but can't really get what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find type of bluetooth device whether mobile or laptop's or mac pc's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989847/find-type-of-bluetooth-device-whether-mobile-or-laptops-or-mac-pcs)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the manufacturer data to identify a device. With the manufacturer id you can find out the manufacturer, then for each manufacturer you would need to find out what the data means.

It is a very time consuming approach and will not work 100% but I don't see another possibility except if you have control over the devices. Then you could advertise the model.

Comment: I was just wondering, how android shows different icons for mobile and PCs in Bluetooth device list ...

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood you. You can use the getBluetoothClass method on the BluetoothDevice object. It is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989847/find-type-of-bluetooth-device-whether-mobile-or-laptops-or-mac-pcs